# How to replace string containing file path using sed

Tags: command-line, sed, text-processing

I want to replace a file path to other using `sed`. I am attaching a small part of my file 
Kindly help

source file :

```
Dir=D:\test\foo
Dir=D:\test\bar
```

the result should look like this

```
Dir=E:\test1\foo
Dir=E:\test1\bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` with pattern grouping:

```
sed -r 's/(.*=)D(:\\[^\]+)(\\.*)/\1E\21\3/' file.txt
```

- All `()` are indicating pattern groups, the purpose of grouping is to use them in the replacement by just using `\#` reference (replace `#` with group number, incrementing from 1, left to right)
- `(.*=)` will match the portion before first `D`, this is referenced as group 1 i.e. `\1` in replacement
- `(:\\[^\]+)` matches upto the second `\` after `D`, this is `\2`
- `(\\.*)` matches everything else after second `\` (including), this is `\3`

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt 
Dir=D:\test\foo
Dir=D:\test\bar

$ sed -r 's/(.*=)D(:\\[^\]+)(\\.*)/\1E\21\3/' file.txt
Dir=E:\test1\foo
Dir=E:\test1\bar
```

---

If you have multiple occurrences and you want to replace them all:

```
$ cat file.txt
Dir=D:\test\foo Dir=D:\bar\foo
Dir=D:\test\bar

$ sed -r 's/D(:\\)[^\]+/E\1test1/g' file.txt
Dir=E:\test1\foo Dir=E:\test1\foo
Dir=E:\test1\bar
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked and i also want to know is there any way we can replace the whole file path with other by mentioning the path in braces or something like that, so that it will be more catchy @heemayl

Comment: @Rooney Could you please give an example and your desired output from that..

Comment: Could you explain the sed please .

Comment: sed -i 's|D:\test|E:\test1|g' file i tried this but it didn't work. I meant something like this. Mentioning the whole path and replacing it with other.

Comment: @monitor35 Added..

Comment: @Rooney Of course you can..`sed -r 's|D:\\test|E:\\test1|g' file.txt` ..just escape `\`

Comment: Why (:\\[^\]+) and not just simply (:\\.*)   . Try to understand but not easy the regexp-extended.

Comment: @monitor35 No problem..the first one is non-greedy and the second one is greedy meaning the second one will greedily match till last `\\` which is definitely not what we want here..